# how to align photos and text

Tags: css, html

How can I insert a photo new to a word, its a quotes so Im trying to do something like

"Everything seems perfect from far away"

but this how it looks

[image]

is there a way to align the last quotes next to away??

```
<p>
  <em>
   <img src="images/quotes-1.jpg" width="45" height="35" style="float:left" alt="quotations"/>  
   Everything seems perfect from far away
   <img src="images/quotes-2.jpg" width="45" height="35" style="float:right" alt="quotations"/>
  </em>
</p>
```

Comment: Remove the `float: left;` and `float: right;` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud remove property **float**.

```
<p>
  <em>
   <img src="images/quotes-1.jpg" width="45" height="35"  alt="quotations"/>  
   Everything seems perfect from far away
   <img src="images/quotes-2.jpg" width="45" height="35"  alt="quotations"/>
  </em>
</p>
```

Comment: Images are [inline by default](http://www.impressivewebs.com/default-css-display-values-html-elements/), so by adding `display: inline` to the images you aren't accomplishing anything except adding unneeded CSS. The important part, and the reason this solution works, is that the floats are removed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float: left;` and `float: right;`. Then add `line-height: 35px;` to the `em`.

Answer (score 1):

To get it looking like that, you will need to remove your `float: left` and `float: right`, then give the images `vertical-align: middle`.

(Please forgive the broken images in the demo, since you didn't provide them with your question.)

**Working Live Demo:**

```css
em > img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <em>
   <img src="images/quotes-1.jpg" width="45" height="35" alt="quotations"/>  
   Everything seems perfect from far away
   <img src="images/quotes-2.jpg" width="45" height="35" alt="quotations"/>
  </em>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the floats. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kcmb6uvp/)

```
        <p>
            <em>
                <img src="images/quotes-1.jpg" width="45" height="35" alt="quotations"/>  
                Everything seems perfect from far away
                <img src="images/quotes-2.jpg" width="45" height="35" alt="quotations"/>
            </em>
        </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding it with an inline-block div

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <p>
      <em>
          <img src="images/quotes-1.jpg" width="45" height="35" style="float:left" alt="quotations"/>  
          Everything seems perfect from far away
          <img src="images/quotes-2.jpg" width="45" height="35" style="float:right" alt="quotations"/>
      </em>
   </p>
</div>
```